# Order status Cancelled on the merchant website considered as relevant proof with legal common sense

Tags: contract-law, business, india

An e-commerce order was returned back to the merchant, but they didn't give me reciept, a practice common in Indian e-eCommerce.
But on the merchants website now the order is marked as cancelled. In terms of relevant proof isn't this ample proof that the business for which the amount was paid is terminated and the moneys should be refunded back to me. I am not a lawyer, but any proof that is registered on a merchant website isnt that a relevant proof?

Comment: @PaulJohnson  please don’t answer in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly relevant *evidence*: on the face of it the order status would seem to be an admission of liability by the merchant. However evidence doesn't quite work like that. Courts don't hear one side and say "thats it, we have all the evidence we need, we don't need to hear the other side". Civil cases like this are decided on the balance of evidence (I'm assuming that the Indian civil system follows the English one in this), so it depends what evidence the other side brings, if any.

Comment: Yes, The Indian Judicial system is a replica of British Model.